# How to show precise data in value axis on amchart XY chart without rounding the decimals automatically?

Tags: formatting, decimal, rounding, amcharts, amcharts4

I've been fiddling with this amchart 4 code for a few days but still could not get it to display the Y axis data precisely, its always tend to round it down or up

Ive tried maxprecision option, numberformat options and many other options and still could not get it parsed properly, data is being loaded via json but for jsfiddle, i have made a similar temp data within javascript

```
chart.data = 
[{"date":"2019-11-07","value":0.0051},
{"date":"2019-11-06","value":0.0063},
{"date":"2019-11-05","value":0.0059},
{"date":"2019-11-04","value":0.0071},
{"date":"2019-11-03","value":0.0101},
{"date":"2019-11-02","value":0.0113},
{"date":"2019-11-01","value":0.0101}];
```

So on the Y Axis It does not show the value as 0.0101, instead its being rounded up to 0.01 instead

here is an example code running on jsfiddle that shows the issue clearly

https://jsfiddle.net/6gck9yz8/

Answer (score 3):

It's a `ValueAxis`. It shows abstract value scale, with grid at values that suits particular value range, and which does not necessarily correspond to your actual data points.

You can increase granularity by decreasing axis renderer's `minGridDistance`. E.g.:

```
valueAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 10;
```

[More about axis grid density](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/positioning-axis-elements/#Setting_the_density_of_the_the_grid_labels).

This will make grid/labels more frequent and thus more precise, but it won't guarantee that these correspond to actual data points.

If you need to absolutely place grid/labels at precise values, you will need to add "axis ranges" for each of those values.

[More info about axis ranges as guides](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/axis-ranges/#Ranges_as_guides).

You can automate it by iterating through all of the data and placing an axis range for each value:

```
for(var i = 0; i < chart.data.length; i++) {
  var range = valueAxis.axisRanges.create();
  range.value = chart.data[i].value;
  range.label.text = chart.data[i].value + "";
  range.grid.stroke = am4core.color("#396478");
  range.grid.strokeOpacity = 0.5;
}
```

Here's a [updated version](https://jsfiddle.net/amcharts/4ds8wo7c/) of your fiddle.

If you run this, you will understand why it's a bad idea to place grid/labels at precise values ;)

[image]